# How do I add a feature to the Explorer panel in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm looking to build an experimental feature into the VS Code Explorer view, similar to this feature: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_explorer-file-nesting

(It's a side project I'm doing for fun, but might turn out to be super cool).

Is it possible to write an extension that enhances the built in "File Explorer" view?(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_views). All the documentation seems to point to creating your own version of it, but not enhancing the existing one.

Greatly appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: you can add menu command and context menu commands to the explorer view, if you have a very cool feature you can create a feature request issue

Comment: Yes, I was reading about that and even saw some examples. But what I want to do is actually alter the displaying of the files themselves (location, filenames). Is it possible in an extension?

Comment: I too am interested in this question

Comment: I am also interested in the answer to this question...

Comment: @rioV8: Can you elaborate on "you can add menu command and context menu commands to the explorer view"?

Comment: @Eric read the VSC extension pages about menu configuration

Comment: @rioV8: the VSC extension pages do not say how to add a menu command to the explorer view, only to its context menu.

Comment: @Eric the buttons on the view title bar are the menu commands depend on which group you add the command.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking you what those groups within the explorer pane are, since they don't appear to be documented.